# Question regarding A/C wiring

Tags: electrical

I have a question regarding A/C wiring: the two pole breaker is wired with black wire on one pole and white wire to the second pole with no marking on white wire. How this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical use of 10/2 NM cable, in this case, to be used to supply a 240 volt compressor or air handler. Yes, the white wire should be marked any time it's repurposed as a hot but it's often left out. IMHO, it's more important to mark it when used in switch loops because the wires can be harder to trace. In a panel like this, It's easy to trace to a breaker but still should be marked. It wasn't marked in my panel and that was the reason the inspector still passed it.

Comment: Personally, I like red as the color to mark hot whites. Any hot color is legal, including black, of course, but red says "this is a marking" louder than a wrap of black tape, or even black heat shrink. Both of those look more like "fixing damaged insulation" to my mental image of the person coming later, but of course, the actual person coming later may see not significance in red; I just think they *should.*

Comment: @Ecnerwal is there a requirement for *how* to mark, like "tape required" or "not paint."

Comment: Not as far as I can find. Tape, paint, heat shrink, or something that hasn't been invented yet are all good.

Comment: @Ecnerwal   I agree. Everyone should see significance in red.   :-)